# In pyparsing, how to I format a nested dictionary output?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm using pyparsing to parse the following input:

```
%FSLAX45Y67*%
```

The output format I'm after, in dictionary form, is:

```
{
  'notation': 'absolute', 
  'zeros': 'leading', 
  'x': {
    'integer': 4, 
    'decimal': 5
  }, 
  'y': {
    'integer': 6, 
    'decimal': 7,
  }, 
  'gerber-command': 'FS'
}
```

The output I'm currently getting is:

```
{
  'notation': 'absolute', 
  'decimal': 6, 
  'zeros': 'leading', 
  'integer': 6, 
  'y': ([6, 6], {'integer': [(6, 0)], 'decimal': [(6, 1)]}), 
  'x': ([6, 6], {'integer': [(6, 0)], 'decimal': [(6, 1)]}), 
  'gerber-command': 'FS'
 }
```

(Note that my question is not about how to make the output look right, but rather how to make pyparsing arrange the data in the way I want.)

With the following code:

```
single_digit = pyp.Regex(r'(\d)').setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))

cmd_format = pyp.Literal('FS')
cmd_format_opt_leading_zeros = pyp.Literal('L').setParseAction(pyp.replaceWith('leading'))
cmd_format_opt_trailing_zeros = pyp.Literal('T').setParseAction(pyp.replaceWith('trailing'))

format_zeros = ((cmd_format_opt_leading_zeros('zeros')) |
               (cmd_format_opt_trailing_zeros('zeros')))

format_notation = ((cmd_format_opt_absolute('notation')) |
                  (cmd_format_opt_incremental('notation')))

format_data = (single_digit)('integer') + single_digit('decimal')

gformat = (inst_del +
           cmd_format('gerber-command') +
           format_zeros +
           format_notation +
           'X' + (format_data)('x') + 
           'Y' + (format_data)('y') + 
           inst_end +
           inst_del)
```

(Some trivial definitions omitted). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pyparsing Group to add structure to the returned tokens. This will probably do the job:

```
gformat = (inst_del +
           cmd_format('gerber-command') +
           format_zeros +
           format_notation +
           'X' + pyp.Group(format_data)('x') + 
           'Y' + pyp.Group(format_data)('y') + 
           inst_end +
           inst_del)
```

Pyparsing's default behavior is to just return a flat list of tokens, so as not to guess at structure just based on what terms are added in what order. For instance, if you had this:

```
aword = Word("A")
bword = Word("B")
cword = Word("C")

preface = aword + bword
body = cword
ending = aword + bword

totalExpr = preface + body + ending

print totalExpr.parseString("AA BB CCC A B").asList()
```

pyparsing would return just the list

```
['AA', 'BB', 'CCC', 'A', 'B']
```

If you want to apply structure (this is especially important to keep nested results names from stepping on each other, as you are seeing in the overlap of integer and decimal), use Group:

```
totalExpr = Group(preface) + body + Group(ending)
```

which gives:

```
[['AA', 'BB'], 'CCC', ['A', 'B']]
```

Here's how this would look if you added results names:

```
preface = aword("As") + bword("Bs")
body = cword
ending = aword("As") + bword("Bs")

totalExpr = Group(preface)("preface") + body("body") + Group(ending)("ending")
print totalExpr.parseString("AA BB CCC A B").dump()
```

Gives:

```
[['AA', 'BB'], 'CCC', ['A', 'B']]
- body: CCC
- ending: ['A', 'B']
  - As: A
  - Bs: B
- preface: ['AA', 'BB']
  - As: AA
  - Bs: BB
```

Because preface and ending are grouped, their duplicate names of "As" and "Bs" are kept separate.

Comment: Your first suggestion gets me closer, but there's still some "residue": {'y': ([4, 3], {'integer': [(4, 0)], 'decimal': [(3, 1)]}), 'x': ([6, 5], {'integer': [(6, 0)], 'decimal': [(5, 1)]}), 'zeros': 'leading', 'notation': 'absolute', 'gerber-command': 'FS'}

Comment: The 'residue' you are seeing is just the repr output of the nested ParseResults. Try accessing the results using the names you have defined: result.notation, result.x.integer, result.y.integer, result.x.decimal, etc. What does result.dump() look like?

Comment: result.dump() looks good. I guess that I was expecting the .asDict() output to look exactly like a dictionary, and I guess that's not the case, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @saardrimer - it may not look like a dict, but you can still use it like one: `result['preface']['As']` -> `"AA"` Also `result.keys()` will give `['preface','body','ending']` and `result['preface'].keys()` will give `['As','Bs']`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setParseAction` liberally to drop information you do not need.
In `format_data` you would need a function which takes the output from `single_digit` and transforms it into the format you want.

```
def _format_data(x):
    return {"integer": x["integer"][0][0],
            "decimal": x["decimal"][0][0]}

format_data.setParseAction(_format_data)
```

Comment: It's not about the actual print format of the output, but how pyparsing captures and organiases the data

Comment: Kind of hard to read from the one line code block. You probably have to add some error checking.

Answer (score 1):

interesting that why difficult questions always end up with recursion?

```
x=\
{
  'notation': 'absolute', 
  'zeros': 'leading', 
  'x': {
    'integer': 4, 
    'decimal': 5
  }, 
  'y': {
    'integer': 6, 
    'decimal': 7,
  }, 
  'gerber-command': 'FS'
}

def superPrint(inidic={},indent='  '):
    for k,v in inidic.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            yield "\n%s'%s': {"%(indent,k)
            for i in superPrint(v,indent+' '*(len(k)+1)):
                yield i
            yield "\n%s},"%indent
        else:
            yield "\n%s'%s': '%s',"%(indent,k,v)

print '{%s\n}'%''.join(superPrint(x))
```

**result:**

```
{
  'y': {
    'integer': '6',
    'decimal': '7',
  },
  'x': {
    'integer': '4',
    'decimal': '5',
  },
  'zeros': 'leading',
  'notation': 'absolute',
  'gerber-command': 'FS',
}
```

NOTE,according to your description of quesion,I am not sure whether or not you want a "," in the last element of a dict.

Try deeper:

```
x=\
{
  'notation': 'absolute', 
  'zeros': 'leading', 
  'x': {
    'integer': 4, 
    'decimal': 5
  }, 
  'y': {
    'integer': 6, 
    'decimal': {'try':7,
                'tryHarder':{'wow':8,
                             'seemsGood':{'wooow':9}}},
  }, 
  'gerber-command': 'FS'
}

print '{%s\n}'%''.join(superPrint(x))
```

SEEMS good:

```
{
  'y': {
    'integer': '6',
    'decimal': {
            'try': '7',
            'tryHarder': {
                      'wow': '8',
                      'seemsGood': {
                                'wooow': '9',
                      },
            },
    },
  },
  'x': {
    'integer': '4',
    'decimal': '5',
  },
  'zeros': 'leading',
  'notation': 'absolute',
  'gerber-command': 'FS',
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in another comment, my question is about getting pyparsing to arrange the data correctly, not about how to prettify the output. (I've modified the question to reflect this.)

Comment: Oh,I don't know what exactly you want this time.Hope your question will be resolved soon:-)

Comment: Good effort. Also, check out the pprint module in the Python std lib. I often use pprint.pprint(parsedData.asList()) to print out a nicely indented list of parsed tokens, when dump() is not what I want.